# How can I solve this problem about energy conservation according to different frames of reference?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, energy-conservation, friction, galilean-relativity

We have two frames of reference: the Earth (E) and a train (T) uniformely moving at velocity u relative to the Earth.
We also have a particle that is initially stationary relative to the train, and is then accelerated by a constant force applied for a time t.
Let's consider this situation only using the Newtonian mechanics (no special relativity involved).

Firstly, suppose there is no friction between the train and the particle: in this case it's easy to show that E and T see two different variations of kinetic energy, but in both cases that variation equals the work made by the force. In particular:

$$\Delta K_E = \frac{1}{2}ma^2t^2+maut$$
$$\Delta K_T = \frac{1}{2}ma^2t^2$$

Now, suppose there is friction between the train and the particle. The problem says: "Let it be supposed that the applied force imparts the same acceleration to the particle for the same previously considered time. Note that there is no change in the initial and final kinetic energies, but another force is required to oppose friction."

I have to show that the energy produced as heat is the same for each observer. The problem also suggests that the work done against the friction depends on the relative motion of the surfaces.

I'm thinking $\Delta E=E_{att}$ where $E_{att}$ is the energy dissipated by friction.
Overall we have:
$$\Delta E=\Delta K-W+E_{att}$$
and since $\Delta K = W$ in both frames of reference, and, for newtonian relativity, $\Delta E$ is invariant, then $E_{att}$ has to be the same too.
I'm afraid this explanation isn't complete though, also because I'm not taking the suggestion into consideration.

The second part of the problem says: "The force applied also performs a work on the train, from the point of view of the observer on Earth, in addition to producing heat and increasing the kinetic energy of the particle. Calculate this work. Is an equal work performed according to the observer on the train? Explain."

I really don't know how to set up this problem, and the way it is written makes me doubt even more about the solution of the first part.

Comment: you need to set up the trajectory in the train frame and integrate Fdx over it, and transform that to earth frame and do it again.

Comment: @JEB since F is constant the integral is basically the product between that force and the space traveld by the particle, which is different in the two frames of reference (1/2at^2 according to T and 1/2at^2+ut according to E). I'm sorry but I don't understand where I should get.